# Invoke debugger programmatically?

Tags: debugging, vbscript, breakpoints, qtp, hp-uft

**Is there a way to invoke the script debugger programmatically?**

I want to create a dialog box that offers an option to start the debugger (as if it had reached a breakpoint in one of the callers), similar to the one that QTP offers when it encounters a playback error.

This is for QTP, but i estimate that if one can do this for VBS, it'll work there too.

**Updated update**

The `stop` statement does what I want -- except for this (in conjunction with QTP/UFT):

- it stops where the `stop` statement is (and not in  the caller's code) (I think I could work around that by putting the function with the `stop` statement into a file that I load in a way that it won't be jumped into by the debugger (`LoadLibrary`? `ExecuteFile`?));
- it requires me to have triggered one "real" breakpoint during the run session previously, and continued execution with "Run"/F5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [`Err.Raise`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf5ze0e.aspx) work for what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, if I would not have to press the "debug" in the dialog.

Comment: @TheBlastOne you said _similar to the one QTP offers when it ecounters a playback error_, you have to click **debug** there too.

Comment: Yeah. But I want my own dialog. Retry for example does not make sense in my case.

Comment: But it´s a good suggestion, +1 cause I should have had that idea myself.

Comment: As long as nothing better is in sight, I´ll have to accept this ;O